# Bind Bootstrap datepicker with Knockout.js viewmodel (ASP.NET Core)

Tags: asp.net-core, knockout.js, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm trying without any success to bind the Bootstrap datepicker control

```
<input class="form-control" data-bind="datePicker : Observation.ObservationDateTime" type="date" />
```

to a Knockout.js viewmodel.  (This is an ASP.NET Core project.)  There are so many moving parts involved in this that I cannot isolate the problem in this specific case.  **What I want to achieve is a simple two-way binding: the date from the viewmodel is populated in the datepicker control; and the date on form submission is sent back to the viewmodel/controller.**

I can verify that the date is successfully passed to the Knockout viewmodel.  To keep track of its value I am currently printing it as text on the page:

```
<div>Viewmodel date as text: <span data-bind="text:Observation.ObservationDateTime"></span></div>
```

It renders like this:

[image]

My research indicates that the setup in the (1) domain model, (2) server side viewmodel, (3) client side (Knockout) viewmodel and the (4) view itself, all matter.  So I have pasted the relevant code from each below:

**Domain model:**

```
    [Required]
    //[Display(Name = "Date/Time")]
    //[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dddd, dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime ObservationDateTime { get; set; }
```

**Server viewmodel/controller:**

```
Observation = new Observation() { ObservationDateTime = _systemClock.Now },
```

**Client Knockout.js viewmodel**

I have tried various bindingHandlers.  Currently (see bit starting 'ko.bindingHandlers.datepicker':

```
CreateObservationViewModel = function (data) {
    var self = this;
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, observedSpeciesMapping, self);

    ko.bindingHandlers.selectPicker = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
            $(element).selectpicker('render');
        }
    };

    ko.bindingHandlers.datepicker = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
            //initialize datepicker with some optional options
            var options = allBindingsAccessor().datepickerOptions || {};
            $(element).datepicker(options);

            //when a user changes the date, update the view model
            ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "changeDate", function (event) {
                var value = valueAccessor();
                if (ko.isObservable(value)) {
                    value(event.date);
                }
            });
        },
        update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
            var widget = $(element).data("datepicker");
            //when the view model is updated, update the widget
            if (widget) {
                widget.date = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
                if (widget.date) {
                    widget.setValue();
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

**Razor view datepicker Bootstrap control:**

```
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="Observation.ObservationDateTime">Date:</label>
                    <input class="form-control" data-bind="datePicker : Observation.ObservationDateTime" type="date" />
                    <div>Viewmodel date as text: <span data-bind="text: Observation.ObservationDateTime"></span></div>
                </div>
```

I think the problem is with the datepicker bindingHandler in the Knockout viewmodel.  However, despite hours of tinkering, I have not solved it.  Any ideas or pointers?

**Update**
**Entire viewmodel**

```
CreateObservationViewModel = function (data) {
    var self = this;
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, observedSpeciesMapping, self);

    ko.bindingHandlers.selectPicker = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
            $(element).selectpicker('render');
        }
    };

    ko.bindingHandlers.datepicker = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
            //initialize datepicker with some optional options
            var options = allBindingsAccessor().datepickerOptions || {};
            $(element).datepicker(options);

            //when a user changes the date, update the view model
            ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "changeDate", function (event) {
                var value = valueAccessor();
                if (ko.isObservable(value)) {
                    value(event.date);
                }
            });
        },
        update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
            //when the view model is updated, update the widget
            var value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
            $(element).val(value).datepicker("update");
        }
    };

    self.addObservedSpecies = function () {
        var observedSpecies = new ObservedSpeciesViewModel({ Id: 0, BirdId: 0, Quantity: 1 });
        self.ObservedSpecies.push(observedSpecies);
    };

    self.removeObservedSpecies = function () {
        if (self.ObservedSpecies().length > 1)
            self.ObservedSpecies.pop();
    };

    self.disableSubmitButton = ko.observable(false);

    self.Total = ko.computed(function () {
        var total = 0;
        total += self.ObservedSpecies().length;
        return total;
    }),


    self.post = function () {
        self.disableSubmitButton(true);
        if (self.ObservedSpecies().length < 1) {
            // ToDo: Implement proper client-side validation of the Observed Species collection
            alert("You must choose at least one observed bird species");
            self.MessageToClient("You must choose at least one observed bird species...");
            self.disableSubmitButton(false);
            return;
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Observation/Post/",
            type: "POST",
            data: ko.toJSON(self),
            headers:
            {
                "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
            },
            success: function (data) {
                var obj = JSON.parse(data);
                if (obj.IsModelStateValid === false) {
                    self.MessageToClient(obj.MessageToClient);
                }
                else {
                    window.location.replace("./Index/");
                }
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                self.disableSubmitButton(false);
                if (XMLHttpRequest.status === 400) {
                    $('#MessageToClient').text(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
                }
                else {
                    $('#MessageToClient').text('The web server had an error.  The issue has been logged for investigation by the developer.');
                }
            }
        });
    };
};

var observedSpeciesMapping = {
    'ObservedSpecies': {
        key: function (obsevedSpecies) {
            return ko.utils.unwrapObservable(obsevedSpecies.Id);
        },
        create: function (options) {
            return new CreateObservationViewModel(options.data);
        }
    }
};

ObservedSpeciesViewModel = function (data) {
    var self = this;
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, observedSpeciesMapping, self);  
};
```

**Razor view snippet**

```
@section scripts{
    <script src="~/js/knockout-3.4.2.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/knockout.mapping-latest.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/jqueryvalidate.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/jquery-validate.bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/createobservationviewmodel.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var createObservationViewModel = new CreateObservationViewModel(@Html.Raw(data));
    ko.applyBindings(createObservationViewModel);
    </script>
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a little uncertain from your description which part isn't working, but there's two issues that I can see.

The first issue is pretty minor and might just be a transcription typo; you're using "datepicker" for the binding definition and "datePicker" in the markup data-bind. Binding names are case sensitive.

The second, primary, issue I think is simply that the date picker doesn't know you've updated the text in its element. Try something like this for your binding's update function:

```
update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
    //when the view model is updated, update the widget
    var value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
    $(element).datepicker("update", new Date(value));
}
```

**EDIT**: Added snippet with working version of your binding

```js
viewModel = function(data) {
  var self = this;
  self.Observation = {
    ObservationDateTime: ko.observable()
  };
}

ko.bindingHandlers.datepicker = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
    //initialize datepicker with some optional options
    var options = allBindingsAccessor().datepickerOptions || {};
    $(element).datepicker(options);

    //when a user changes the date, update the view model
    ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "changeDate", function(event) {
      var value = valueAccessor();
      if (ko.isObservable(value)) {
        value(event.date);
      }
    });
  },
  update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
    //when the view model is updated, update the widget
    var value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
    $(element).datepicker("update", new Date(value));
  }
};

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>


<input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="datepicker : Observation.ObservationDateTime" style="width: 120px; margin:8px;" />
<div>Viewmodel date as text: <span data-bind="text: Observation.ObservationDateTime"></span></div>
<br/>
<span>Manual change: </span><input type="text" data-bind="textInput: Observation.ObservationDateTime" />
```

Comment: Hi, if I update the HTML to lower case "datepicker", I get Uncaught TypeError: Unable to process binding "datepicker: function (){return Observation.ObservationDateTime }"
Message: $(...).datepicker is not a function'

Comment: The issue is that the datePicker does not update with the viewmodel date value.

Comment: @Winthorpe The selectPicker or the datePicker? I don't see the selectPicker being used anywhere

Comment: @Winthorpe double-check that your binding is declared as all lower-case, and also that it's being declare outside of your view-model. I hadn't noticed until right now that the declaration is within the view-model itself. Try moving it to just above your ko.applyBindings

Comment: I can update the viewmodel from the datePicker if I use "value" bindind instead of the "datePicker" binding: '<input class="form-control" data-bind="value : Observation.ObservationDateTime" type="date" />'

Comment: @Winthorpe I don't think your bootstrap datepicker is ever being initialized so that makes sense. It's just using it like a text input.

Comment: I've pasted the entire viewmodel in the edited question (except for the validation script).  The ko.applyBindings is in the Razor page (also now pasted above

Comment: @Winthorpe Does anything change if you move your bindingHandlers into the scripts section just above ko.applyBindings?

Comment: No change.  I moved both bindingHandlers across.  The selectPicker continues to work.  The datePicker is exactly the same I'm afraid (i.e. not binding).

Comment: @Winthorpe "$(...).datepicker is not a function" sounds like it's trying to bind before the bootstrap library is loaded. When do you load boostrap.js and boostrap-datepicker.js?

Comment: In the Razor page, in the section scripts.  The order is:

Comment: <script src="~/js/knockout-3.4.2.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/knockout.mapping-latest.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/jqueryvalidate.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/jquery-validate.bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/createobservationviewmodel.js"></script>

Comment: So the viewmodel script is last

Comment: @Winthorpe hmmm and you're sure you have boostrap-datepicker.js too? I don't see it in that list, but I'm guessing that's not a full list.

Comment: I was not loading boostrap-datepicker.js.  I am now and there is no change.

Comment: Just for info, in case it helps, the Bootstrap datePicker control does load.  It has the calendar menu and the up/down arrows to change the date one day at a time.  It always has loaded, but without the date from the viewmodel

Comment: @Winthorpe You might be seeing the native browser up/down arrows and calendar popup because of type="date" on your input. It's a little confusing having both.

Comment: I see.  Yes I removed 'type="date"' and it renders just like an ordinary text input

Comment: Here's a fiddle with a working version of your binding at least. I'm not sure I can figure out the other problem(s) without creating a full repro. https://jsfiddle.net/jlspake/rspLx45y/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help @Jason Spake

Comment: I've managed to get it working using the solution you kindly provided in the fiddle.  I also resolved some conflicts when loading the selectpicker.js.  If you want to post your fiddle as an answer I will mark it as such.  Otherwise I will accept your answer posted earlier.  Thank you again.

Comment: @Winthorpe Great I'm glad it's working. I've added the fiddle into my answer as a snippet.

Comment: Thank you again.  I appreciate your help  :)